# sed / awk / grep find string between semicolons

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I have a huge text file with something like that:

```
igflex01; igflexdev01; igdbstg01;
igldapint01; igjetdev01; igsql01;
igesxstg01; igdbint01; igdmstg01;
igdsdev01; igdmmmo01; igmsgint02;
```

and so on...

I would like to extract all text between semicolons when the string 'int' is present.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What would your desired output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for sed / grep, here it is:

```
> cat file
igflex01; igflexdev01; igdbstg01;
igldapint01; igjetdev01; igsql01;
igesxstg01; igdbint01; igdmstg01;
igdsdev01; igdmmmo01; igmsgint02;

> sed -nr 's/\s*;\s*/\n/gp' file | grep int
igldapint01
igdbint01
igmsgint02
```

Or get it with only a single sed call...

```
> sed -nr -e 's/\s*;\s*/\n/g;/int/P' file
igldapint01
igdbint01
igmsgint02
```

Answer (score 2):

Used the "tr" command to replace the semicolons with newlines and then run grep (which is line-oriented).

```
$ cat input.txt | tr ';' '\n' | grep int
 igldapint01
 igdbint01
 igmsgint02
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to cheat and convert the `;` into newlines and then you can just grep
eg

```
tr ';' '\012' | grep int
```

eg

```
$ cat x
igflex01; igflexdev01; igdbstg01;
igldapint01; igjetdev01; igsql01;
igesxstg01; igdbint01; igdmstg01;
igdsdev01; igdmmmo01; igmsgint02;

$ cat x | tr ';' '\012' | grep int
igldapint01
 igdbint01
 igmsgint02
```

Note that it has the spaces in some cases because the space *is* in between the `;`s.  Also note that the first word of a line (which isn't *strictly* between `;` on a line, but is between them in the data) is also returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
% echo 'aint;int;cint' | perl -nle 'print for grep /int/, split /\s*;\s*/'
aint
int
cint
%
```

Or just `split ";"` to preserve any whitespace between.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat abc.txt 
igflex01; igflexdev01; igdbstg01;
igldapint01; igjetdev01; igsql01;
igesxstg01; igdbint01; igdmstg01;
igdsdev01; igdmmmo01; igmsgint02;

$ grep -o '[^;]*int[^;]*' abc.txt 
igldapint01
 igdbint01
 igmsgint02
```

If spaces are not desired:

```
$ grep -o '[^ ;]*int[^ ;]*' abc.txt 
igldapint01
igdbint01
igmsgint02
```